# ADODB imported .csv change data type

Tags: vba, excel

I have some very large .csv files that I want to query and pull entries out. I've set this up using ADO in Excel 2016 successfully, or so it seemed, and remarkably fast. I am looking to query a field ID using;

```
SELECT * FROM <file> WHERE ID = #.
```

This has worked fine up until the ID numbers which contain letters, i.e. 960545H4. These appear much further down the file, around ~400k rows in.

I believe the problem is that excel is assuming this field (under the header ID) is numeric based one the first x number of entries. I want this to be set to text.

Is there anyway to set the datatype of the field/column so that I can query successfully?

```
Sub testSQL()

Dim xlcon as ADOB.Connection
Dim xlrs as ADOB.RecordSet
Dim nextRow as Integer
Dim datafilepath as String
Dim datafilename as String

Set xlcon = New ADOB.Connection
Set xlrs = New ADOB.RecordSet
datafilepath = "U:\Common\"
datafilename = "test_file"

xlcon.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
xlcon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & datafilepath & ";" & "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited,"""

xlcon.Open

xlrs.Open "SELECT * FROM [" & datafilename & ".csv] WHERE ID = '023487562HH'", xlcon

'the rest of the code...
```

I was hoping something slong the lines of;

```
SELECT * FROM [file] WHERE CStr(ID) = 34897562FD
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You can use a [schema file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver?view=sql-server-2017) to describe the fields of your text resp. csv file. But I would suggest to use [Get & Transform](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/get-transform-in-excel-881c63c6-37c5-4ca2-b616-59e18d75b4de) instead

Comment: I'm not familiar with schema.ini. Do I literally just create the file and leave it in the same folder? Get & Transform has been painstakingly slow, this worked wonders one generic number IDs.

Comment: Just had a whirl with schema.ini, worked like a charm @Storax! Thank you, you should have posted this as an answer!

Comment: No Problem, but it would be great if you posted your solution now for all the others who might be also in need of this.

Comment: Your post `SELECT * FROM [file] WHERE CStr(ID) = 34897562FD` wouldn't work as it would need to be `SELECT * FROM [file] WHERE CStr(ID) = '34897562FD'`

Comment: Yeh I've accidently missed the ' out when typing it out!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Storax's recommendation on using a schema file I have got this working.

I created a schema file in the same location as the file. The file looked like;

```
[test_file.csv]
Format=CSVDelimited
ColNameHeader=True
MaxScanRows=0
```

I can now return the IDs I am looking for! Many thanks to Storax for this solution!

Answer (score 2):

One could take Killuminati's solution and add also the field names as needed. The parameter `MaxScanRows` just makes sure that the OLEDB driver will scan the whole file as stated also in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver?view=sql-server-2017)

> The data types of the fields can also be determined. Use the
>   MaxScanRows option to indicate how many rows should be scanned when
>   determining the column types. If you set MaxScanRows to 0, the whole
>   file is scanned. The MaxScanRows setting in Schema.ini overrides the
>   setting in the Windows Registry, file by file.

In order to declare the data type for each field one could use a schema.ini like that

```
[test_file.csv]
Format=Delimited(;)
DecimalSymbol=,
ColNameHeader=False
Col1=Field1 Text 
Col2=Field2 Text 
Col3=Field3 Text 
Col4=StartDate Date
Col5=EndDate Date
Col6=Price Currency
```

The entry after the equal sign is name of the field resp. column. If the file contains a header it can be the same but does not have to but it is required.

Code could look like that

```
Sub ADO()
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim myPath As String
    myPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TextFiles\"
    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & myPath & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited()"";"
    With rs
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
        .Open "SELECT * FROM [test_file.csv]"
        .AddNew
        .Fields("Field1") = "Doe"
        .Fields("Field2") = "John"
        .Fields("Field3") = "123456"
        .Fields("StartDate") = Date
        .Fields("EndDate") = "05.10.2018"
        .Fields("Price") = 1234.56
        .Update
    End With
    conn.Close
End Sub
```