# Access 2016 Type Conversion Errors when importing csv files

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a macro that imports 2 csv files into an Access 2016 database.  1 file goes to a *BEFORE* table and the other goes to an *AFTER* table.  All of the data imports just like I expect it to with the exception of zip codes longer than 5 characters.  Anything less than 5 is not an issue.  Any zip code like 12345-1245 doesn't import into the database.  I'm guess it has to do with the hypen in the middle of it but I don't know how to correct it.  The zip code field in both tables is defined as 'short text'.

I really need the zip codes to appear as they are (12345-1245) because the macro runs a number of queries against all of the fields to identify differences in the 2 tables.

So if 1 table has 12345 and the other has 12345-1245, it should appear on the differences.  I don't really want to modify the zip code because this could cause issues for the reviewer if they have to look at all of the modified zip codes.

Is there a way to import the longer zip codes without creating Type Conversion issues?  Thanks in advance for your help with this issue....

Comment: You might have a length limit of 5 character as [field size](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/set-the-field-size-ba65e5a7-2e6f-4737-8e72-36b93f966a33). Try changing to 10 or remove any number. Does an error table output after Excel import?

Comment: You can store `12345-1245` as `123451245` (number) and use zip+4 formatting to display the zip properly. This also corrects 4 digit zips with leading zeroes.

Comment: @user11121185 Storing postal codes as numbers is generally a horrible idea - works (kind of) in the U.S., but not in Canada, the U.K., etc., etc..  ;-)

Comment: @Comintern.............I have separate tables for the US and Canada.  This issue only impacts the US import process

Comment: @Parfait.........I just checked and the field size is 255.  I didn't change the default when I set up these fields.  Yes......an error table is created after the import is finished.  It says (1) Type Conversion, (2) field name, and (3) row number.  There are 9 lines on this table and when I checked the source data, there are 9 zip codes that are longer than 5 characters.

Comment: @user11121185......I'm going to give this a try.  I have another similar process and the longer zip codes don't have an issue with that process / database.  In fact, this process was built off of that one since it works so well.  Not sure what the difference is.  The only thing I can think of is that the source data is from different applications........

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the import code? I suspect you need a schema file for the csvs.

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well, look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver?view=sql-server-2017) resp. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52519647/6600940)

Comment: @Comintern...This is the line of code that does the import process:  .DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "", "US_Before", "R:\ProB\Before_Data.csv", True

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transfertext . I'd suggest to use _SpecificationName_ with a schema.ini

Comment: @Storax.............Thanks..........I'll look at adding a specification name as you suggest